# Basic Physics question

Tags: physics

Velocity vector $A$ has components $A_x=3 \text{ m/s}$ and $A_y=4 \text{ m/s}$. A second velocity vector $B$ has a magnitude that is twice that of $A$ and is pointed down the negative $x$-axis. Find the $x$ component of $B$

This is what I did:
Magnitude of A=5
so magnitude of B is 10
Bx= 10cos180=-10
Is this correct? 
What I am hesitant about is this sentence "**pointed down the negative $x$-axis**"

Comment: I got that BX=-10...Is that correct?

Comment: @Zoey please edit this into your question and how you got $-10$, then we'll be able to better help you

Comment: $B_x=-10$ m/s is correct.

Comment: Yes, it's correct. But you didn't explain how you got the number 10.

Comment: "Pointed down the negative $x$ axis" is not the clearest description. And of course the answer depends entirely on what was meant by that phrase. But I would interpret it the same way you did. Your work looks fine to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The magnitude of $A$ is $|A|=\sqrt {3^2 + 4^2} = 5$ and we know that $|B| = 2|A| = 2 \cdot 5 = 10$. The part about $B$ pointing down the negative axis means $B_y = 0$ and $B_x < 0$. Using this we know, $\sqrt{B_x^2 + 0^2} = 10 \implies |B_x| = 10 $. And since the problem states it is pointing in the negative direction, $B_x = -10$.

Or another method, as you've shown is to use the angle of vector $B$ and $B_x = |B|\cos \theta$. In this example $\theta = \pi = 180^\circ$, and therefore, $B_x = 10 \cos \pi = -10$.